# GE Profile Evaporator fan constantly running

Tags: refrigerator, noise

I have 14-year-old GE Profile fridge. 3 years ago the evaporator fan started making a loud hum (fluctuating around 100Hz) at apparently random times. Following advice from a YouTube video, I used a blow-dryer near the back panel of the freezer, which didn't help. It only deformed the plastic part covering the fan. An unofficial repairman replaced the fan and the problem was fixed. A few weeks ago, it started to make the same noise. This time however, a replacement by another repairman didn't solve the problem, and within hours of replacement, the humming noise started again. Initially it would happen every couple of days, but it gradually happened more often. I was advised to lubricate the shaft. When I removed the fan, I realized that the second one that had been working for several years had an operating voltage of 12 rather than the 9.75 of the original. Also neither the original one, nor the second one seemed to have a sensor, while this new one has a ceramic piece that is attached to the evaporator coils by a metal clasp.
After spraying some DW40 lubricant around the shaft, I noticed a white plastic piece around the shaft that was not attached to the fan but had an outer circumference matching the top gasket (or grommet?) of the mount. I removed the piece thinking it might be the culprit for the noise.
I mounted the fan back on the frame, and turned on the freezer. The fan started turning with normal sound, but the front display of the fridge didn't come until the compressor/condensor started working about 6 hours later. The refrigeration cycle seems to be going on unimpared, but the fan stayed on for all of the 7 hours at which point, I unplugged the fridge again. Is it normal for the evaporator fan to work all the time? And what about the compressor/condensor. Is it normal for them to start with such a long delay after plugging the fridge (which by the way had grown to almost room temperature while the fridge was off)?  Could its control board have been damaged? Prior to the humming noise, it also made some rattling sounds that I thought might be due the defrost, but apparently the overload relay can make similar sounds.

Comment: That sounds like something might not be tightly attached and is resonating. Motor mountings do sometimes fail.